# Oracle ORDS including SOAP support

Tags: oracle, rest, soap

Oracle ORDS (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e87809/developing-REST-applications.htm#AELIG90103) offers nice " auto " features such as support for offset, limit, filtering with filter clauses, filterobject gramar, etc.

However, in our current environment, we primarily use SOAP so what I don't know is if there is a solution out there which can handle both SOAP and REST input and provide the same filterobject gramar.

So e.g. instead of specifying the filter in the URL as with REST, specify the filter in the SOAP message or header and have a layer of re-usable components in the database which handle this filtering.

Is there a generic approach for both / best practice?

Comment: SOAP is a protocol and REST is an architectural style. They are two fundamentally different things, so you're not going to get something which can do this out of the box for you. Tim Hall's article of APEX_WEB_SERVICE illustrates this very nicely. [Check it out](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_web_service-consuming-soap-and-rest-web-services)

Answer (score 1):

ORDS is focused on REST support for the Oracle Database. It has no support for SOAP and no plans to add.